# What kind of arithmetic can turn $(a+bi)$ into $(b+ai)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to define some code to convert a complex number in the form of $(a+bi)$ into one of the form $(b+ai)$. I guess I am trying to find some operand $x$ such that $(a+bi)x = (b+ai)$.

I can switch where the $i$ is located:

$$\begin{align}
(a+bi)\times i &= (ai+bi^2)) \\
&= (ai+b(-1)) \\
&= (ai-b) \\
&= (-b+ai)
\end{align}$$

But then I'm not sure how to change that $-b$ into a $b$. Is there some arithmetic I can do on a complex number to move the $i$ from $a$ to $b$?

Comment: Note:    $\dfrac i {a+bi} = \dfrac  {b+ai} {a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Multiply by $(a+bi)$ by $-I$ to get $(a+bi)(-i) = b-ai$. Then take the complex conjugate of the result $(b-ai)^* = b+ai$.

Comment: $z\to i\bar z\,$ where $\,\overline{a+bi} = a-bi\ $ denotes *conjugation*. $\ \ $

Comment: Multiply by $i$ and add $2b$.

Comment: Identify your complex number $a+bi$ with the vector $\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr}$, and multiply by the matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}$. That gives you the vector $\pmatrix{b\cr a\cr}$, which you then identify with the complex number $b+ai$.

Comment: $(a+bi)x = (b+ai) \Rightarrow x=\frac{b+ai}{a+bi}=\frac{(b+ai)(a-bi)}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's 'bout this:

$a + bi \overset{\times i}{\longrightarrow} ia - b \overset{\times -1}{\longrightarrow} -ia + b \overset{\text{conjugate}}{\longrightarrow} b + ia, \tag 1$

or this:

$a + bi \overset{\text{conjugate}}{\longrightarrow} a - bi  \overset{\times i}{\longrightarrow} b + ia; \tag 2$

that is, with

$z = a + bi, \tag 3$

$z \longrightarrow \overline {(-iz)} = i\bar z. \tag 3$

Comment: Is there a canonical name to the operation of converting $(a+bi)$ to $(b+ai)$?

Comment: @gator:  none that I know. Thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!